# Angular 8 - Chartist - Not LOADING Charts in the TABLES

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, charts, datatables

I'm trying to replicate a carousel function using datatables, bootstrap 4 and chartist.

The IDEA is to generate a list of CARDS based on the records returned from db with its own CHART (BAR CHART) - the component also has a lot of other functions that is happening fine but display of charts is a problem. The first chart shows fine but from second chart onwards I get a `Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null` issue.

I've the following setup:
Master Component (dashboard-graph-component):

1. Has a Table List
2. Table has one column with a angular component
   (dashboard-graph-single-component)
3. It has INPUTs attributes to load
   master data and an method in the AfterInit to load chart data.

I've set the max rows to show in the table as 1 so to ensure I show only graph card at one time and pagination is going to show another chart in next page.

The Issue:
If I have 10 rows in the table - I am able to see the BAR GRAPH only on the first ROW - rest all are not visible but with following errors for all subsequent calls:

```
core.js:5847 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.Chartist.createSvg (chartist.js:328)
    at constr.createChart (chartist.js:3670)
    at constr.initialize (chartist.js:1842)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:24328)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:498)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
    at timer (zone.js:3070)
```

Code for master component:

```
<div class="table-responsive align-self-center">
            <table datatable id="showtime-tables" class="table responsive table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0"
            [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="all">{{ dataTable.headerRow[0] | translate}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows;let k=index">
                  <td> 
                    <app-showtime-single-resolution class="col-md-12" *ngIf="showListCarousal"
                    [passedResolutionId]="row[0]" 
                    [resolutionMaster]="this.resolutionList.length>=k?this.resolutionList[k]:0" >
                   </app-showtime-single-resolution>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

The Single Component:
HTML:

```
<div class="card card-chart">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-icon card-header-danger">
                      <div class="card-icon">
                        <i class="material-icons">pie_chart</i>
                      </div>
                      <h4 class="card-title">Line Chart</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div id="{{'chartPreferences2' + this.passedResolutionId}}" class="ct-chart ct-golden-section">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Code :

```
var chartId = '#chartPreferences2'+ this.passedResolutionId;
     setTimeout(() => {
     new Chartist.Bar(chartId  , dataSimpleBarChart, optionsSimpleBarChart,
     responsiveOptionsSimpleBarChart);
    }, 500);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue seems to be with DATAGRIDs - as during pagination datatables.net angular component DOES not create the DOM and before chartist can generate the chart itself - parent selector is queried and since this is not yet created by the first page of the GIRD - the chartist is complaining. So I now need to figure out how to keep datatables.net to generate entire DOM with pagination support or refresh the chart compnent on each pagination change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with DATAGRIDs - as during pagination datatables.net angular component DOES not create the DOM and before chartist can generate the chart itself - parent selector is queried and since this is not yet created by the first page of the GIRD - the chartist is complaining. So I now need to figure out how to keep datatables.net to generate entire DOM with pagination support or refresh the chart compnent on each pagination change.